# theano g++ not detected, But I have successfully installed g++

Tags: python, g++, pycharm, theano, deep-learning

After successfully installed theano, I use：

```
import theano
```

It just show me the Warning:

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will
 default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
```

**g++ not detected ! But I have successfully installed g++:**

```
C:\Users\dell>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,
fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)
```

I want to optimize my program and use GPU to speed up, How can I fix this problem? Thank you very much!

- Win7,64 operate system
- installed MinGW
- Pycharm
- theano-0.8.2, python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first `import theano` , I meet the error `error: '::hypot' has not been declared`, I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536788/g-error-on-import-of-theano-on-windows-7) to successfully import it.

Then following steps worked for me on win10

1. install mingw64
2. add `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin` to PATH
3. restart computer

then the warning disappeared