# g++ error on import of Theano on Windows 7

Tags: g++, theano, importerror

I'm attempting to get setup with a proper g++ installation according to [the theano installation guide](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows). I've previously had theano working with the python only implementation. I'm using the bleeding edge version of theano from their git repo on python 3.4. I've tried using the theano suggested TDM-GCC-64 method as well as MinGW, and both result in the exact same error. (copied as readable as possible)

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -shared -g -march=skylake -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 
-mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mmovbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt 
-mabm -mno-lwp -mfma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mbmi -mbmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx 
-mavx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mlzcnt -mrtm -mhle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase 
-mrdseed -mprfchw -madx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f 
-mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mclflushopt 
-mxsavec -mxsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl 
-mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit -mno-mwaitx 
-mno-clzero -mno-pku --param l1-cache-size=32 --param 
l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=8192 -mtune=skylake 
-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 
-IC:\Python34_64bit\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
IC:\Python34_64bit\include -IC:\Python34_64bit\lib\site-packages\theano\gof
-o C:\Users\Jwely\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.4.4-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd 
C:\Users\Jwely\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.4.4-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp 
-LC:\Python34_64bit\libs -LC:\Python34_64bit -lpython34


In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\6.1.0\math.h:36:0,
from C:\Python34_64bit\include/pyport.h:328,
from C:\Python34_64bit\include/Python.h:50,
from C:\Users\Jwely\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_94_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.4.4-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\6.1.0\cmath:1133:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared
    using ::hypot;
            ^~~~~
```

It may be worth noting that before it prints this error, it prints an entire file worth of code, you can find the entire error output here

I'm not sure what to try next, I've followed the directions twice, used a couple different installation methods for some dependencies, and made sure to clean up my system path between each attempt and reboot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Go to your user folder: C:/Users/[username]
2. Create .theanorc file if it doesn't already exist
3. makes sure it includes the lines:

   ```
   [gcc]
   cxxflags = -D_hypot=hypot
   ```

Comment: Don't know why this why downvoted, great fix, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: How am I supposed to create a file without a name? Windows doesn't allow me to.

Comment: Ah, found it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce

Comment: export CXXFLAGS=-D_hypot=hypot

Answer (score 4):

["Error: '::hypot' has not been declared" in cmath while trying to embed Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683358/error-hypot-has-not-been-declared-in-cmath-while-trying-to-embed-python)
[Error building Boost 1.49.0 with GCC 4.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660524/error-building-boost-1-49-0-with-gcc-4-7-0)

my solution is comment out all the

```
#define hypot _hypot
```

macro in the pyconfig.h file

Comment: This worked for me.... but I wonder if other applications could have problems with the absence of "_hypot".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. Go to `System properties/Advance system setting`
2. Add your MinGW installation path, if already added and looks something like `C:\{your MingW installation}\bin` 
   change it to `C:\{your MingW installation}`

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are probably a better, more permanent solution. For a quick fix, the following worked for me:

```
import theano
theano.config.gcc.cxxflags = "-D_hypot=hypot"
```

...with Windows 10, Anaconda 4.4, Python 2.7, Theano v0.10.0.dev1, m2w64-toolchain v5.3.0

Comment: If you add the quotes marks it gives you an error: g++.exe: error: "-D_hypot=hypot".  Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

if you can't create a file with name `.theanorc`.
You can use this code in console but before open cmd in `C:/Users/[username]` and then write `python` and then paste below code there:

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"], ".theanorc"), "w") as f:
    f.write("[gcc]\ncxxflags = -D_hypot=hypot")
```

Answer (score -1):

First, uninstall all Theano versions.

Then:

```
pip install pydot-ng

conda install mingw libpython

pip install git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
```